# Splitting word by specific char work with string but don't work with argv[1]

Tags: c

I have an issue with my program.
My program split word using \t \n or space and put the word into a array of string.
when i call my function like this its works perfectly :

```
ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces("Hello Everyone this is a test"));
```

but when i try to send the first command line param like this :

```
ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces(argv[1]));
```

i'm getting the following error :

./a.out "test test tast"
a.out(97132,0x7fff706ff000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9e09403228: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    97132 abort      ./a.out "test test tast"

here is the code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// This func return the word nbr
int     ft_compte_mot(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == '\n') {
        i++;
        while (str[i] != '\0') {
            if ((str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t') &&
                (str[i + 1] >= '!' && str[i + 1] <= 'z')) {
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (j + 1);
}
// this func count the word lenght and put them in an int array
int     *ft_compte_taille_mot(int *taillemot, char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')  {
        j = 0;
        while ((str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t')
                && str[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\t'
                && str[i] != '\0')  {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        taillemot[k] = j;
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    return (taillemot);
}

void    ft_copy_word(int *taillemot, int nbmot, char **tab, char *str)  {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0' && k < nbmot) {
        j = 0;
        while ((str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t')
            && str[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        while (j < taillemot[k]) {
            tab[k][j] = str[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        //tab[k][j] = '\0';
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    tab[nbmot] = 0;
}

char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str) {
    int     nbmot = ft_compte_mot(str);
    int     *taillemot;
    int     i = 0;
    char    **string;

    if ((taillemot = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nbmot)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ft_compte_taille_mot(taillemot, str);
    if ((string = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (nbmot + 1))) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < nbmot) {
        if ((string[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * taillemot[i] + 1))
                == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        i++;
    }
    ft_copy_word(taillemot, nbmot, string, str);
    return (string);
}

void    ft_putchar(char c) {  
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)    {
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')  {
        ft_putchar(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void    ft_print_words_tables(char **tab) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (tab[i] != 0) {
        ft_putstr(tab[i]);
        ft_putchar('\n');
        i++;
    }
    ft_putchar('\n');
}
```

EDIT : Here is the main EDIT 2 : I also tested with argv[1]

```
char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str);
void    ft_print_words_tables(char **tab);

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
   write(1, &c, 1);
}

 int        main(int argc, char **argv) 
 {
    ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces(argv[1]));
    return (0);
 }
```

FYI i'm in school and we have a particular norm, we can't use for loop or a bunch of libc function.
I'm really stuck here and i really don't understand why it's work with "   " but not with **argv

thx by advance for your help

Comment: I see no actual call here! Please provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't posted the actual `main` function at all.

Comment: Use `valgrind` or some similar tool to debug. You're writing out of bounds in `ft_compte_taille_mot` line 46.

Comment: also, why are you using an **int** array for the string, `char`s are integral numbers too in C?

Comment: I added the main, sorry for the mistake.
I use and int array to stock the lenght of each number.

Comment: argv is already a list of strings split by whitespace, at least usually. To pass whitespace in argv[1], try wrapping the arguments to your program in quotes.

Comment: `*argv` is `argv[0]`, not `argv[1]`.

Comment: `ft_compte_mot` occurs buffer over run.

Comment: `ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces(*argv));` occurs memory leak.

Comment: Hi guys my main was another test, i know that i need to pass argv[1], and anyway i always do ./a.out "test test tast"

Comment: i just don't understand why it works perfectly when im doing this ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces("Hello Everyone this is a test"));

Comment: Also i pass my arg like that ./a.out "test test1 test2"

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution :

```
char *str;
str = argv[1];
str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';
ft_print_words_tables(ft_split_whitespaces(str));
return (0);
```

thanks for the help

Comment: That writes outside the bounds of `argv[1]`.